# Feature selection using the penalizedLDA package

Tags: r

I am trying to use the penalizedLDA package to run a penalized linear discriminant analysis in order to select the "most meaningful" variables. I have searched here and on other sites for help in accessing the the output from the penalized model to no avail.

My data comprises of 400 varaibles and 44 groups. Code I used and results I got thus far:

```
yy.m<-as.matrix(yy)   #Factors/groups
xx.m<-as.matrix(xx)   #Variables

cv.out<-PenalizedLDA.cv(xx.m,yy.m,type="standard") 
  ## aplly the penalty
out <- PenalizedLDA(xx.m,yy.m,lambda=cv.out$bestlambda,K=cv.out$bestK)
```

Too get the structure of the output from the anaylsis:

```
> str(out)
List of 10
$ discrim: num [1:401, 1:4] -0.0234 -0.0219 -0.0189 -0.0143 -0.0102 ...
$ xproj  : num [1:100, 1:4] -8.31 -14.68 -11.07 -13.46 -26.2 ...
$ K      : int 4
$ crits  :List of 4
  ..$ : num [1:4] 2827 2827 2827 2827
  ..$ : num [1:4] 914 914 914 914
  ..$ : num [1:4] 162 162 162 162
  ..$ : num [1:4] 48.6 48.6 48.6 48.6
$ type   : chr "standard"
$ lambda : num 0
$ lambda2: NULL
$ wcsd.x : Named num [1:401] 0.0379 0.0335 0.0292 0.0261 0.0217 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:401] "R400" "R405" "R410" "R415" ...
$ x      : num [1:100, 1:401] 0.147 0.144 0.145 0.141 0.129 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : NULL
.. ..$ : chr [1:401] "R400" "R405" "R410" "R415" ...
$ y      : num [1:100, 1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
- attr(*, "class")= chr "penlda"
```

I am interested in obtaining a list or matrix of the top 20 variables for feature selection, more than likely based on the coefficients of the Linear discrimination.
I realized I would have to sort the coefficients in descending order, and get the variable names matched to it. So the output I would expect is something like this imaginary example

```
 V1       V2
R400      0.34
R1535     0.22...
```

Can anyone provide any pointers (not necessarily the R code). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `out$K` is 4, and that means you have 4 discriminant vectors. If you want the top 20 variables according to, say, the 2nd vector, try this:

```
# get the data frame of variable names and coefficients
var.coef = data.frame(colnames(xx.m), out$discrim[,2]) 
# sort the 2nd column (the coefficients) in decreasing order, and only keep the top 20
var.coef.top = var.coef[order(var.coef[,2], decreasing = TRUE)[1:20], ]
```

`var.coef.top` is what you want.

Comment: @ cogitivita, thanks a million. It works great!! I was going onto 10 lines of code already, Glad it got broken down to just 2 lines. Thanks again.